# LocalHost8080 error page

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

When I run the following script `npm run dev` the localhost output is the current file structure. Instead I need it to render the Welcome component. I am trying to identify the root cause, whether it be webpack.config.js, project architecture, etc. Here is my webpack.config.js file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPLugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
 context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
 entry: "./main.js",
 module: {
 loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015']
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPLugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use:['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      publicPath: './dist'
    })
   }
 ]
},
 output: {
 path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
 filename: "[name].bundle.js",
},
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "./dist"),
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
},
plugins:[
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
 ]
};
```

package.json dev:"webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base dist/  --hot"

Project Architecture
[image: project]

Main.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";



import Welcome from "./components/Welcome";

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<Welcome/>, app);
```

Welcome.js

```
import React from "react";

export default class Welcome extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h4>Welcome Component</h4>
  </div>
  );
 }
}
```

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="main.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Localhost Output
[image: localhost:8080]

Terminal
[image]

Comment: Can you include what is in your main.html too please?

Comment: You are not including your bundle file in your main.html?

Comment: Also can you include your server.js (I presume you are using express server).

Comment: @ChrisCousins I am I just updated the question with the corrected script tag

Comment: @ChrisCousins I did not know I needed a server js file. I am relatively new when it comes to webpack dev. I assumed since I installed web pack-dev-server I did not need any additional servers.

Comment: @ChrisCousins I added the server.js but the component is not rendering. I also changed the file structure a little bit. Do you mind looking over my updates? https://github.com/gURLmeetsCode/react_portfolio.git

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `publicPath: '/dist/'`, in your `devServer` object in webpack config or replace main.html to root directory.

Answer (score 0):

After further review, I decided to update my configuration with webpack middleware based on the observation from Chris Cousins. I added express.js and server.js file to the project. Thank you!